# Can't get a Service to modify the Registry using CreateProcess on a Script

Tags: c++, windows, service, registry, createprocess

-I have a Service running under Local System (no desktop interaction)

-I have a .js Script that makes a simple registry change in HKLM\software\ ...

Snipet:

```
try{
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
regvalue = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(regvalue);
WshShell.RegWrite(regkey, regvalue, regtype);
}
```

-The script modifies the registry successfully when run through command prompt and double clicked

-The script also produces a text file upon completion. Either a "success.txt", or an "error.txt" in the case that WshShell.RegWrite() "catches"

This is how I am calling the script in the service (only hard coding for testing)

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
bool bRes = false;
TCHAR appCmdLine[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\wscript.exe //NOLOGO C:/Test/testpatchHKLM.js");
bRes = CreateProcess(NULL, appCmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

**The CreateProcess returns true, the success text file is created by the script, but the registry remains unmodified.**

*Notes: 1) Sending the first parameter as NULL was mentioned in lots of other places, in fact that's the only way I got the script to successfully run.
2) the script has no UI or interaction with the user
3) shellexecute was producing the same behavior*

I know there are a million easier ways to accomplish this, but my goal is to get THIS method working

I'm assuming it's something like wscript.exe not having permissions, but I shouldn't have to get the usertoken and runas since the service is creating the process...

Comment: Most likely problem: you're writing to a part of the registry that has separate 32-bit and 64-bit views.  (Note that you're launching the script as a 32-bit process.)

Comment: Calling stuff from `SysWOW64` is running them under _WoW64_, are you sure you're checking the 32 bit (not 64 bit) registry for changes?

Comment: Thanks guys, had no idea there was a %systemroot%\syswow64\regedit that was different than regedit